# Open local files

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to open a local file in default app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
var file = new File("content://" + path);
var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, BuildConfig.ApplicationId + ".provider", file);
intent.SetDataAndType(uri, GetMimeType(path));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

When it calls `FileProvider.GetUriForFile` the crashes. I found that I should add providers to `androidmanifest.xml`:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
                android:authorities="PACKAGENAME.fileprovider" 
                android:exported="false" 
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

But I can't find `androidmanifest.xml` in `Xamarin.Forms` android project. How can I open this file in `Xamarin.Forms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `androidmanifest.xml` file in .Android project under properties.